# Edit sqlrpgle file over ftp with vim

Tags: vim, ftp, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm having an issue with vim while I'm trying to remotely edit a sqlrpgle file in AS/400. I'm using the next command to open the file in vim:

```
:e ftp://myusername@mydomain/mylibrary/mymember.myfile
```

The file opens up but is filled with @ characters instead of source code. Am I calling it the wrong way?

I tried writing the command this way but it failed:

```
:e ftp://myusername@mydomain/mylibrary/mymember.myfile.sqlrpgle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "@" characters (0x40) are EBCDIC spaces.

Enable ASCII transfer mode with the following netrw option:

```
:let g:netrw_ftpmode="ascii"
```

Edit files using the following format:

```
:e ftp://user@host/library/file.member
```